# Twisted web server behind apache - no resource found

Tags: python, apache, proxy, twisted

I am running twisted.web.server on localhost at port 8001 and apache2 with mod_proxy.
Apache is set to proxy according to the following config

```
http://localhost/jarvis ----> http://localhost:8001/
```

The httpd config for this rule is

```
ProxyPass /jarvis http://localhost:8001/
ProxyPassReverse /jarvis http://localhost:8001/
```

The twisted app's code fragment for server config is as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
root = Resource()
root.putChild("clientauth", boshProtocol())
logging.basicConfig()
factory = Site(root)
reactor.listenTCP(8001, factory)
reactor.run()
```

When I go to

```
http://localhost:8001/clientauth
```

it runs as expected.
However when I use

```
http://localhost/jarvis/clientauth
```

It give the error - "No such child resource."
As i understand - the request is correctly proxied to the twisted web server. But why is the child resource not identified?

Comment: Have you printed out what URL you are receiving in Twisted 'request'? It sounds like it's passing it to twisted without removing the /jarvis  so you are receiving the whole url

Comment: How do we do that? can you please elaborate.

Comment: Off the top of my head subclass type twisted.web.resource.Resource create the Site object with that as the argument and in the getChild() function print the request. Not exactly what your after but you can extrapolate: [Example](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/web-in-60/dynamic-dispatch.html)

Comment: Ohh .. I see I did this and found that the path that twisted receives is "//". I need to change my apache directive to remove the trailing hash from the actual URL. This solved the problem. However would that create problems in the future? 
Anyway, thank you very much @JoeDoherty for your insight.

Comment: no problem @mlakhara . It shouldn't cause a problem that I can see but I would keep this in mind when writing the rest of your code. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a RewriteRule. I haven't tested it, but the fix for your problem is more or less like this:

`RewriteRule   ^/jarvis/(.*)   /$1`

Be sure to have mod_rewrite enabled.

Here is a link I usually use for reference: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Good luck!